# Alexa access token is being cached

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, token, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Alexa Skill, which relies on Account Linking and an Access Token.

In my skill, I set the access token as such:

`config.HEADERS.AUTH.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + event.session.user.accessToken;`

When I initially add the skill in Alexa Companion App, I go through my 3rd party app's Login page which generates the initial Token.

If I log out of my 3rd party app (From the web app), the Alexa Companion App doesn't recognize that I've logged out and continues using the token. So, I `unlink` the skill, and re-add the skill. Instead of taking me to the login page, it automatically links the skill.

This tells me Amazon seems to be caching the initial access token.

How can I prevent this?